# Insert from C# into Oracle triggers doesn't execute

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, oracle

I have weird problem: I'm running an insert statement into Oracle which seems to work fine, but the trigger in Oracle does not work

```
using (OracleConnection dbConnection = new OracleConnection("ConnectionString"))
{
    dbConnection.Open();
    OracleCommand dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand();
    OracleTransaction dbTransaction =  dbConnection.BeginTransaction();
    dbCommand.Transaction = dbTransaction;

    try
    {
        dbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        dbCommand.CommandText = "insert statment goes here";
        dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        dbTransaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (OracleException ex)
    {
        dbTransaction.Rollback();
        Response.Write(ex.StackTrace);
    }

    dbConnection.Close();
}
```

When running this in VS2013 triggers in Oracle doesn't execute it :( , but when I make the insert statement from Oracle directly it's fired and every thing is okay

Comment: What do you mean by _dose not work_ exactly? You get any exception or error message? Did you debug your code line by line and see what is going on?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with Oracle.  A trigger should be entirely transparent to the consuming application.  If the code needs to *tell* the database to use the trigger then it isn't really a trigger...

Comment: the trigger on the oracle dose not work the above code run with out any errors and the insert statement done with no problems but the trigger on oracle dose't work

Comment: show us the trigger code

Comment: how are you checking whether the trigger is not executed ????

Comment: OK. I deleted an answer and let's @Mohamed continues to search in wrong direction.